# Rails Heroku precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep getting these erros and can't figure out what is wrong. It runs just fine locally. I'm using rails 4 but tried adding 'config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false' to my application file anyway and that didn't seem to work either... There's a lot of JS related errors showing but it doesn't make sense to me why that would be causing a precompile error when my js works locally... please help!

I've also successfully deployed smaller apps (mostly static apps with crud functionality) with the same gems and structure just fine. and I've read though [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) but still no luck with figuring this out.

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#' (line: 14484, col: 0, pos: 401076)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:11936)
remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:12155)
remote:        at parse_error (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:13967)
remote:        at Object.next_token [as input] (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:19118)
remote:        at next (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:20436)
remote:        at semicolon (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:21281)
remote:        at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:24179
remote:        at /tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:22307
remote:        at /tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2659:21493
remote:        at /tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2660:1595
remote:        at Object.parse (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2660:1804)
remote:        at apply.source (eval at <anonymous> (/tmp/execjs20160101-998-rgd264js:2957:8), <anonymous>:19:26)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2659:11936)
remote:        js_error ((execjs):2659:12155)
remote:        parse_error ((execjs):2659:13967)
remote:        Object.next_token [as input] ((execjs):2659:19118)
remote:        next ((execjs):2659:20436)
remote:        semicolon ((execjs):2659:21281)
remote:        simple_statement ((execjs):2659:24179)
remote:        (execjs):2659:22307
remote:        (execjs):2659:21493
remote:        (execjs):2660:1595
remote:        Object.parse ((execjs):2660:1804)
remote:        apply.source (eval at <anonymous> ((execjs):2957:8), <anonymous>:19:26)
remote:        /tmp/build_056617320f808f4615f61ed299226754/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'

[removed some lines]      
/tmp/build_056617320f808f4615f61ed299226754/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to secure-ocean-2024.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/secure-ocean-2024.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/secure-ocean-2024.git'
```

Comment: try to run `rake assets:clean assets:precompile -- trace` on local machine.

Comment: @AmitSharma thank you!! app is now on heroku :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Heroku doesn't properly precompile assets, so you need to run `rake assets:precompile` locally, then do another commit and push to Heroku. This can affect all the assets - not just JavaScript code (so if your style isn't showing up like you expect, try precompiling assets locally).

Also, make sure you have the Heroku gem in production which enables Heroku to serve up assets in production.

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Finally, make sure you're still calling the assets in the head of your application.html.erb file - for example (without turbolinks):

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Then, to use images, make sure you put them in the assets>images folder and then use the Rails helper [image_tag](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) to call them... to access the image rails.png in the app/assets/images directory your erb should look like this:

```
<%= image_tag "rails.png" %>
```

For more on the Rails asset pipeline, see the docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: after precompiling locally, do you know why image and js files wouldn't have compiled? I got my app on heroku (progress yay) but images and js are missing. The only file in the assets folder that showed up was application.css :/

Comment: Do you already have the rails_12factor gem in production?  I just added that to the answer also.

Comment: yea I do, written just like that

Comment: So you ran `rake assets:precompile` locally, git-committed all the changes (adds things to your public folder) and pushed to Heroku again, and you're still missing the files?  Just checking.

Comment: Yea. I guess I'm having a hard time understanding where everything is going when you precompile. So in Inspect element I see in the Sources tab there's no assets/application.js fie, but in the Resources tab there is a Scripts/application.js file. I also have images that 'cannot be found' but do exist in Resources inside Images/

Comment: Can you add a link to your repo on Github?

Comment: Sorry I just got back on today - looks like you may have accidentally deleted your asset loading tags in the head of your application.html.erb. :)
https://github.com/melmar12/Vendit_v2/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: I updated the answer to show that and also to give more info on the Rails asset pipeline.  Your javascript tag was missing from the head of your html.  For your images, you may be trying to call your images directly in html, but you need to use the image_tag helper instead because Rails puts a hash on the image file names every time they are compiled.

Comment: I had the javascript_include_tag at the end of the body tag, but I just moved it back in the head tag without turbolinks but it still isn't rendering like I thought it would... I changed all my img tags and those are now working, so thats one less thing to worry about!

Comment: You may need to require them in the application.js if they aren't compiling into there automatically - https://github.com/melmar12/Vendit_v2/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: I did, and it looks like it is being compiled in application.js, but nothing still

Comment: Which javascript file do you think is not getting compiled?

Comment: 'custom-scripts.js' I created a new question with more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580543/javascript-not-running-as-expected-in-ruby-rails-app-deployed-on-heroku