# Javascript not running as expected in ruby rails app deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using Rails 4 and have an app deployed on Heroku. I've been precompiling my assets locally, but my javascript isn't working as expected.

my application.js file looks like this('custom-scripts' has all my important functions in it):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.slick
//= require custom-scripts
//= require_tree .
```

On Chrome's dev tools under the Resources tab I see that Frames/appname/Scripts/application.js exists with the code in 'custom-scripts.js' at the bottom of the file. In the Elements tab, the script tag is linking to /assets/application.js but under the Sources tab inside appname/assets/ I don't see application.js only application.css.
I'm using the `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` tag so it should link correctly right?

I've been reading about the Assets pipeline and everything I'm seeing says that everything should be working. I wrote a `test()` function that just returns a console.log function in my custom-scripts file and when called in the Console tab, it returns 'function not defined' so that tells me my functions aren't even running for some reason. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more of a dirty fix, but it works, so for now this is my solution; So I removed `//= require_tree .` and `//= require custom-scripts` from application.js and added `<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom-scripts' %>` to my application.html.erb file then ran `rake assets:precompile` again, pushed to github & heroku and bam, its working wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` yes, it is correct but it only pre-compile your scripts. have you tried creating a file in the `assets/javascript`? If you have `user_controller.rb` in the `controller folder`, i usually create a coffee script pertaining to that controller. i.g `users.js.coffee` there you can create or call your custom-script:

```
$(document).ready ->
         ...
```

I hope it helps mate. gl

Comment: I do have other empty js.coffee files that were generated for my controllers, but I don't use them because the functions I wrote I need fore all my pages/views. So I just created a custom-scripts.js file and put them in there.